# some extra directories in macOS PATH variable

Tags: macos, shell, environment-variables, path, oh-my-zsh

I can't figure out where some extra directories come from in my PATH variable
As a shell I am using oh-my-zsh. In the .zshrc there are the following lines:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/Documents/Development/flutter/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
export PATH=”${PATH}:/$ANDROID_HOME/tools:/$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:/$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools”
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/gradle@6/bin:$PATH"
```

But there are some extra directories in my PATH variable:

```
➜  ~ echo $PATH    
/Users/kosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/bin:/Users/kosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2@global/bin:/Users/kosh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/bin:/usr/local/opt/gradle@6/bin:”/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/kosh/Documents/Development/flutter/bin:/Users/kosh/.rvm/bin://tools://tools/bin://platform-tools”
```

Where do these directories like

```
/Users/kosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/bin
/Users/kosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2@global/bin
/Users/kosh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/bin
```

come from?

Comment: Did you or have you installed ruby?

Comment: Yes, I did it a long time ago. The question is where do these values of PATH come from. Does Ruby add them somewhere?